# Toggle Visibility of an Uncontrollable Element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hubspot

I have Hubspot chat script embedded in the `index.html` file of my React App using the `<script/>` tag for user communication.

Now, when a button is clicked I want the hubspot container to be hidden and then when another button is clicked I want it to be displayed again.

I do not have control over the behaviour of the chat icon because it was added to the page via a `<script/>` tag.

But after some digging I was able to get the id of the element so here is how I've tried toggling the visibility of the chat but it's not working for me.

```
const toggleHubspotContainer = (turnOn) => {
        let hubSpotContainer = document.getElementById("hubspot-messages-iframe-container");
        if (turnOn) {
            hubSpotContainer.style.display = 'block';
            return;
        }
        hubSpotContainer.style.display = 'none'; //The chat icon is not hiding even after this
    }
```

Please note that the hubspot script was added in the `index.html` file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js-eu1.hs-scripts.com/adadadad.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to do this properly?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share how the Hubspot is implemented?

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans The hubspot was added via a single script tag like this in the index.html file:

  ```<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js-eu1.hs-scripts.com/adadadad.js"></script>```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, consider your script is in header

```
function hideHb() {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  var js = document.getElementById("hs-script-loader");
  head.parentNode.removeChild(js);
}
```